# COQ Proof Assistant - Apply the hyppothesis

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm working on a very simple proof assignment in Coqide.
I'm trying to apply hypothesis **H2** to my **subgoal**, but for some reason it's not working.
I cannot figure out why; can someone explain why `apply H2.` command is not applicable.

```
2 subgoals
A : Type
x : A
l1, l2 : list A
H : Prefix l1 l2
H2 : x :: l2 = (x :: l1) ++ [] -> Prefix (x :: l1) (x :: l2)
______________________________________(1/2)
x :: l2 = (x :: l1) ++ []
______________________________________(2/2)
exists l3 : list A, x :: l2 = (x :: l1) ++ l3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply H2` has no chance to work because its conclusion is `Prefix (x :: l1) (x :: l2)` which doesn't look like your goal.
The premise of `H2` *is* your goal: `x :: l2 = (x :: l1) ++ []` however, which means you can only `apply` `H2` if you manage to solve your goal first… not very useful.